ParquetWriter is significantly slower in linux enviroment than my local machine
Below is my code of writing data into parquet file.
ParquetWriter<Group> writer = new ParquetWriter<>(path, ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE,groupWriteSupport, CompressionCodecName.UNCOMPRESSED,ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE, ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, true, false, DEFAULT_WRITER_VERSION, conf);
List<Group> dataList = buildGroupsForDataList(dataIntoDbVo.getDataList(), dataIntoDbVo.getColTypeLst(), schema);
for (Group group : dataList) {
    writer.write(group);
}

The code runs well on my local machine, 50k line of records can be written in less than 5 seconds. However when I run this in a Linux enviroment (the app is packed to a docker image and runs in the Cloud platform), it takes 20-50 mins to write the same amount of data.
My guess is that hadoop is installed on my local machine, while in Linux, it uses builtin-java classes. But I'm not sure if this could explain the huge performance difference.
I have tried to minimize the page size and change compressionCodec, it seems have a litter improvement.
I also change the ParquetWriter<Group> to AvroParquetWriter, but there is no significant performance difference.
